# PythonでURLのリストから特定のIDを抽出したい

Tags: python, python3, selenium

seleniumを使って、yahoo newsのwebサイトからURLを抽出して
IDのみ取得したいです。

**実現したい内容**
❶からURLを取得してから、❷IDのみ取得したいです。

❶URL取得

```
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435551']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435550']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435548']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435547']
```

❷ID取得

```
['6435551'、'6435550'、'6435548'、'6435547']
```

現在は下記のコードで❶までのURLを取得できますが、
❷のID取得できません。
実現の結果のprint(new_list)のように[]空白として出力されます。
スライス方法が間違っていいますでしょうか。

もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。
お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

**現在の結果**
print(data_list)
※一部省略

```
['https://www.yahoo.co.jp/']
['https://support.yahoo-net.jp/PccNews/s/']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/ranking/access/news']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/paidnews?source=pc-common-glonav']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/domestic']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/world']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/business']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/entertainment']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/sports']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/it']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/science']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/life']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/categories/local']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/top-picks']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/top-picks']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/top-picks']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/domestic']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/world']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/business']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/entertainment']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/sports']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/it']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/science']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/local']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435551']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435550']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435548']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435547']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435546']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435545']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435544']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435542']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435543']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435541']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435539']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435538']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435537']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435535']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435534']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435532']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435533']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435531']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435530']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435528']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435527']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435524']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435525']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435526']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435521']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/topics/top-picks?page=2']
['https://www.facebook.com/yjnews']
['https://twitter.com/YahooNewsTopics']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/newshack/']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/flash']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/live']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/info/commercial-transactions']
['https://support.yahoo-net.jp/voc/s/news']
['https://support.yahoo-net.jp/PccNews/s/']
```

print(l_in)
※一部省略

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435552']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435551']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435550']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435548']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435547']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435546']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435545']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435544']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435542']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435543']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435541']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435539']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435538']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435537']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435535']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435534']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435532']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435533']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435531']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435530']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435528']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435527']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435524']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435525']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435526']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

**print(new_list)**
※一部省略

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

コード

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select  
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

option = Options()

#ログイン情報を維持するための設定　
# 参考→https://rabbitfoot.xyz/selenium-chrome-profile
PROFILE_PATH ="C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\" # 変更
option.add_argument('--user-data-dir=' + PROFILE_PATH)
option.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
#Getting Default Adapter failed error message
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

# ブラウザを開く設定
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install() ,options=option)

#news.yahoo URL
URL= "https://news.yahoo.co.jp/"

# URLを開く。
driver.get(URL)

#待機時間
time.sleep(3)

while True:
    try:
        #ボタンクリック top25まで
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uamods-topics"]/div/div/div/div/p[1]/a')
        button.click()

        #待機時間
        time.sleep(3)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        break


#待機時間
time.sleep(3)

#全てのURLを抽出
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for element in elements:
    list=element.get_attribute("href")


    #URLをリストとして作成
    data_list = list.splitlines()
    #print(data_list)

    #URLに含んでいるpickupのURLのみ　出力
    l_in = [s for s in data_list if 'pickup' in s]
    #print(l_in)

    #IDを取得
    new_list=l_in[32:]
    print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

今の処理では得られた`l_in`がリストであり、その中にURLの文字列が1個入っているか空(0個)なのですから、文字列が入っている場合は`[32:]`ではなく`[0][32:]`になります。

質問の中の`print(l_in)`結果例の抜粋：

```
    ....
[]
[]
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435552']
['https://news.yahoo.co.jp/pickup/6435551']
    ....
[]
[]
```

それまでの段階的な処理を生かしておいて、少ない改造で実現する場合は以下のようになるでしょう。
この部分を：

```
    #IDを取得
    new_list=l_in[32:]
    print(new_list)
```

こうすれば、`ID`が得られると思われます。

```
    #IDを取得
    if l_in:
        new_list=l_in[0][32:]
        print(new_list)
```

ただし固定の桁数で切り出すのはあまり良い処理とは言えないので、正規表現とか @metropolis さん回答のように理解しやすい文字で切り分ける方が良いでしょう。

それから変数名は`new_list`になっていますが上記処理で取り出せるのはリストではなく個々の`ID`ですね。
最終的に`IDのリスト`が欲しい(@merino さん @metropolis さんの回答にコメントしたように)のならば取得したその位置で表示するのではなく以下のようにいったんリストに追加してからループを抜けた後で表示することです。

```
new_list = []  #### 空のリストを定義して初期化
for element in elements:
    list=element.get_attribute("href")

    #URLをリストとして作成
    data_list = list.splitlines()
    #print(data_list)

    #URLに含んでいるpickupのURLのみ　出力
    l_in = [s for s in data_list if 'pickup' in s]
    #print(l_in)

    #IDを取得
    if l_in:
        new_list.append(l_in[0][32:])  #### ループ内ではリストに追加するだけ

print(new_list)  #### ループ終了後にまとめて表示
```

---

ちなみにseleniumの4.3.0以後だと`find_element_by_**`や`find_elements_by_**`が削除されるようです。
[AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72754651/9014308)

なので使うselenium版数を新しくした場合は以下の行等を変更する必要があるでしょう。

```
        #ボタンクリック top25まで
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uamods-topics"]/div/div/div/div/p[1]/a')
```

```
#全てのURLを抽出
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。期待通りの結果になりました。またseleniumの件、参考になりました。

Answer (score 1):

下記でどうでしょうか？

```
for element in elements:
    href=element.get_attribute("href")
    if 'pickup' in href:
        print(href[32:])
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。こちらの方法はシンプルで勉強になりました。
ちなみにですが、`['6435551'、'6435550'、'6435548'、'6435547']`分割して出力したいですが、可能でしょうか。下記のように分割してみましたが、上手くできませんでした。もし分かりましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。
`if 'pickup' in href:
      data_list= href[32:]

      data_list.split()
      print(data_list)`

Answer (score 1):

```py
#URLに含んでいるpickupのURLのみ出力
l_in = [s.split('/')[-1] for s in data_list if 'pickup' in s]
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。こちらの方法ですとこちらのよう出力されます。
空欄の[]も付きます。`['6435551'、'6435550'、'6435548'、'6435547']`のように空欄なしで出力可能でしょうか。もし分かるのでしたら教えていただける幸いです。
`
[]
[]
['6435565']
['6435564']
['6435562']
['6435561']
['6435560']
['6435559']
[]
[]
 `

Comment: おそらく、`l_in = sum([s.split('/')[-1] for s in data_list if 'pickup' in s], [])` とすればよいかと思います。